# MongoDB with Drupal 7

Tags: mongodb, drupal-7

I want to use MongoDB with Drupal 7 for the speedup of performance. How can we use a MongoDB in my Drupal website for any particular module. My Drupal site is a social networking site and I want to use MongoDB for statuses module (posting status and comments and displaying them). How can I integrate MongoDB for a specific module?

Answer (score 0):

There's a native Mongo library for PHP, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php for getting started and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [module for MongoDB](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb). Haven't used it myself but I think that you need some kind of addition to work with the modules you require. There should be enough code though to get you started.

There is no just-install solution for your requirement though.

If you need performance tuning with regular RDBMS, there is [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) with its performance logging features, that also shows queries and highlights the ones that take longer than `n` seconds. This might be a better solution than just throwing in a new technology.